# joining 2 tables in msqli

Tags: php, mysqli

[table posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oTiK.png)

[table users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ggu2.png)

how would i count posts for specific user logged in. for example when user with id 3 is logged in it should show me 4 posts
I already did it for total posts count:

```
<?php
$post_query1 = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM posts "; 
$post_result1 = mysqli_query($db, $post_query1); 
$post1 = mysqli_fetch_array($post_result1); 
?>
```

Comment: Using conditions in WHERE clause (You don't need joining for this): `SELECT count(*) AS total FROM posts WHERE id_users = 3`

Answer (score 0):

You have only to use a simple join.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM USER u,
          post p
WHERE p.id_user = u.id_user
AND u.id_user = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below example :

```
select count(*) as total from user as u inner join post as p on  p.id_user = u.id_user AND u.id_user = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the posts count for the particular user, say user with id = 3, your query should be this:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM posts WHERE id_users = 3";
```

But if you want to get both the posts count as well as the user information and other post information, you will have to run a join query on both the `users` and `posts` table. Your query would now become:

```
$query = "SELECT u.*, p.*, count(p.id_posts) FROM users AS u JOIN posts AS p ON u.id_users = p.id_users WHERE p.id_users = 3";
```

**Some Useful Notes**

`p.*` - `*` is a wildcard character that means get all the columns in the `posts` table
`u.*` - `*` is a wildcard that means get all the columns in the `users` table
`posts` as p - `AS` is for aliasing. So, we are giving `posts` table a temporary name.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the different types of the JOINs in SQL:

**(INNER) JOIN:** Returns records that have matching values in both tables

**LEFT (OUTER) JOIN:** Return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table

**RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN:** Return all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table

**FULL (OUTER) JOIN:** Return all records when there is a match in either left or right table

> **Note:** It is necessary that you have to **join** two/more tables only with the help of **foreign key**. Without the foreign key is is meaningless to join two or more tables

Reference 1: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Reference 2: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

As per the Question what you have asked to join the tables

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 JOIN TABLE 2 ON TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id WHERE TABLE2.ID=3
```

Kindly replace `TABLE1 & TABLE2` with the Tables that are to be joined and the `id` with the foreign key what you have specified in the Table.

Hope so this might be helpful for you to write your own code in future. Happy Coding :)